# Get the maximum text width of a column inside SELECT statement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm convinced someone else must have had this same issue before but I just can't find anything.

Given a table of data:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    [COL_NAME] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [COL_AGE] int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT N'Column 1', 4 UNION ALL
SELECT N'Col2', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT N'Col 3', 56 UNION ALL
SELECT N'Column Four', 8 UNION ALL
SELECT N'Column Number 5', 12 UNION ALL
SELECT N'Column Number Six', 9;
```

If I use SSMS and set my output to text, running this script:

```
SELECT [COL_AGE], [COL_NAME] AS [MyCol] FROM @Table
```

Produces this:

```
COL_AGE     MyCol
----------- -----------------
4           Column 1
2           Col2
56          Col 3
8           Column Four
12          Column Number 5
9           Column Number Six
```

Note that the data is neatly formatted and spaced.

I want to display the contents like SQL does when you post your results to text:

```
'Column 1         '
'Col2             '
'Col 3            '
'Column Four      '
'Column Number 5  '
'Column Number Six'
```

The following is just to describe what I want, I understand it's obviously a horrible piece of script and should never make its way into production:

```
SELECT 
    N'''' + LEFT( 
        [COL_NAME] + SPACE( ( SELECT MAX(LEN([COL_NAME])) FROM @Table ) )
        , ( SELECT MAX(LEN([COL_NAME])) FROM @Table ) 
    ) + N'''' 
FROM @Table
```

Originally, I tried this script, which is what I'm trying to get right:

```
SELECT 
    N'''' + LEFT( 
        [COL_NAME] + SPACE(MAX(LEN([COL_NAME])))
        , MAX(LEN([COL_NAME])) 
    ) + N''''
FROM @Table
```

But it returns the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 28 Column '@Table.COL_NAME' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The script is part of a much bigger script and it all has to happen within the SELECT statement, I can't use external variables to first look up the MAX(LEN()) because the bigger script iterates through other tables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used a quick CROSS APPLY to get the length of the buffer you want to use:

```
select
    N'''' + LEFT( 
        [COL_NAME] + SPACE( t2.MLEN )
        , t2.MLEN 
    ) + N''''
from @Table
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT MAX(LEN([COL_NAME])) MLEN FROM @Table )  t2
```

Comment: I was so close and yet so far, I thought of this but thought it was going to be horrible performance wise but I went ahead and tried it out and it was actually just what the doctor ordered.  Thanks!!

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side. You provided this approach faster than me :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get, what you are trying to achieve, but I think, this might be what you need:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    [COL_NAME] nvarchar(30) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT N'Column 1' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Col2' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Col 3' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Column Four' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Column Number 5' UNION ALL
SELECT N'Column Number Six';
```

--The query

```
WITH ComputeMaxLength(ml) AS(SELECT MAX(LEN(t.COL_NAME)) FROM @Table t)
SELECT LEFT(CONCAT(tbl.COL_NAME,REPLICATE('.',ml)),ml)
FROM ComputeMaxLength
CROSS JOIN @Table tbl;
```

The result

```
Column 1.........
Col2.............
Col 3............
Column Four......
Column Number 5..
Column Number Six
```

The idea in short:

We use a CTE to compute the needed value.
Then we `CROSS JOIN` this with the source table. As the CTE will return just one row in any case, this will not add rows to our result. But it will add a column to our result, which we can use to compute a padding...

Hint: I used a dot instead of a blank to make the effect visible

### UPDATE *Cannot use a `WITH` / CTE*

You can shift the computation into an `APPLY` like here

```
SELECT CONCAT('''',LEFT(CONCAT([COL_NAME],SPACE(ml)),ml),'''')
FROM @Table
CROSS APPLY(SELECT MAX(LEN([COL_NAME])) FROM @Table) A(ml);
```

The engine should be smart enough to execute this just once...

### UPDATE 2: If you cannot use an APPLY either

Your own code, which is *obviously a horrible piece of script and should never make its way into production*, is not bad (just ugly :-) )

I'd put it like this

```
SELECT CONCAT(''''
             ,LEFT(CONCAT([COL_NAME]
                         ,SPACE((SELECT MAX(LEN([COL_NAME])) FROM @Table)))
                  ,(SELECT MAX(LEN([COL_NAME])) FROM @Table))
             ,'''')
FROM @Table;
```

The engine should be smart enough to reuse the result in this case too (and avoid multiple executions of the `SELECT MAX()...`...

Comment: Thanks for this, I've added more information to my question.  It MUST be a SELECT as it's part of a bigger SELECT statement, I can't use WITH.

Comment: Thanks for this, I gave @JM_ the answer as he was first but I did still give you an up vote.  Appreciate the time!

Comment: @Storm, That is perfectly okay, Happy Coding!